# drop down menu is not displaying any options

Tags: php, jquery, mysqli

I don't think I am writing the code below correctly but I want to be able to retrieve the value from the module drop down menu on another page. Below is the code where it contains a blank drop down menu and outputs the number and name of the module selected:

```
$sql = "SELECT CourseId, CourseNo, CourseName FROM Course"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId, $dbCourseNo, $dbCourseName);

 $courses = array(); // easier if you don't use generic names for data 

 $courseHTML = "";  
 $courseHTML .= '<select name="courses" id="coursesDrop" onchange="getModules();">'.PHP_EOL; 
 $courseHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) 
 { 
     $courseno = $dbCourseNo;
     $course = $dbCourseId;
     $coursename = $dbCourseName; 
     $courseHTML .= "<option value='".$course."'>" . $courseno . " - " . $coursename . "</option>".PHP_EOL;  
  } 

  $courseHTML .= '</select>'; 

    $moduleHTML = "";  
        $moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
        $moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  
        $moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 


        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">

        function getModules() { 
        var course = jQuery("#coursesDrop").val(); 
        jQuery('#modulesDrop').empty(); 
        jQuery('#modulesDrop').html('<option value="">Please Select</option>'); 
        jQuery.ajax({ 
        type: "post", 
        url:  "module.php", 
        data: { course:course }, 
        success: function(response){ 
        jQuery('#modulesDrop').append(response); 
        } 
        }); 


        }


        </script> 

    <?php

    if (isset($_POST['moduleSubmit'])) {    

    $outputmodule = ""; 

    $moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
    $moduleId = $moduleInfo[0];
    $moduleNo = $moduleInfo[1];
    $moduleName = $moduleInfo[2];
    $outputmodule = sprintf("<p><strong>Module:</strong> %s - %s</p>", $moduleNo, $moduleName);

    ....

    ?>
```

Below is the module.php page where it displays the module number and name in the drop down menu depending on the course selected:

```
<?php

$course = isset($_POST['course']) ? $_POST['course'] : ''; 

    $sql = "
    SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, c.CourseNo, m.ModuleNo,
    c.CourseName,
    m.ModuleName
    FROM Course c
    INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
    JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
    WHERE
    (c.CourseId = ?)
    ORDER BY c.CourseId, m.ModuleId
    "; 

     $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

     $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$course);

     $sqlstmt->execute(); 

     $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseNo,$dbModuleNo,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);


    $moduleHTML  = "";  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
         $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%2$s - %3$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);
    } 


    echo $moduleHTML; 

     $sqlstmt->execute(); 
    ?>
```

At the moment nothing is being displayed in the drop down menu except for the "Please Select" option

UPDATE:

Ok if you look at the editsessionteacher.php script, it contained the code below which worked:

```
$outputmodule = ""; 

        $moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
        $moduleId = $moduleInfo[0];
        $moduleName = $moduleInfo[2];
        $outputmodule = sprintf("<p><strong>Module:</strong> %s - %s</p>", $moduleId, $moduleName);
```

The module.php was this:

```
$course = isset($_POST['course']) ? $_POST['course'] : ''; 

$sql = "
SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId,
c.CourseName,
m.ModuleName
FROM Course c
INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
WHERE
(c.CourseId = ?)
ORDER BY c.CourseId, m.ModuleId
"; 

 $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

 $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$course);

 $sqlstmt->execute(); 

 $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);


$moduleHTML  = "";  

     while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
         $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s_%2$s">%1$s - %2$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleName);
    } 


echo $moduleHTML; 

 $sqlstmt->execute();
```

But I want to add the moduleNo into the drop down menu, so when I tried to change the code to this below, it doesn't work:

editsessionteacher.php:

```
$outputmodule = ""; 

$moduleInfo = explode("_", $_POST['modules']);
$moduleId = $moduleInfo[0];
$moduleNo = $moduleInfo[1];
$moduleName = $moduleInfo[2];
$outputmodule = sprintf("<p><strong>Module:</strong> %s - %s</p>", $moduleNo, $moduleName);
```

module.php:

```
    $course = isset($_POST['course']) ? $_POST['course'] : ''; 

    $sql = "
    SELECT cm.CourseId, cm.ModuleId, c.CourseNo, m.ModuleNo,
    c.CourseName,
    m.ModuleName
    FROM Course c
    INNER JOIN Course_Module cm ON c.CourseId = cm.CourseId
    JOIN Module m ON cm.ModuleId = m.ModuleId
    WHERE
    (c.CourseId = ?)
    ORDER BY c.CourseId, m.ModuleId
    "; 

     $sqlstmt=$mysqli->prepare($sql);

     $sqlstmt->bind_param("s",$course);

     $sqlstmt->execute(); 

     $sqlstmt->bind_result($dbCourseId,$dbModuleId,$dbCourseNo,$dbModuleNo,$dbCourseName,$dbModuleName);


    $moduleHTML  = "";  

$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
     $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%2$s - %3$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);
} 

$moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

echo $moduleHTML;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you never call the javascript function `getModules()` that would make the request to get new options. Try adding this within your `<script>` tag:

```
jQuery(function(){
  jQuery("#coursesDrop").change(getModules); 

})
```

Comment: So what is the best way to change my code in both scripts in order to be able to get the drop down menu working again?

Comment: OK.. I misread that the code above was in 2 files. Actually the closing of `select` is correct. Also the jQuery ajax appears to be correct. It appears you never call the `getModules()` function. Give me a couple of minutes to update my answer

Comment: I added the course drop down menu which I did not include, in the course drop down menu it does contain the getModules() function

Comment: OK..then you need to inspec the ajax request in a browser console to make sure it is being made. If it is being made need to see what data is sent and returned. Is `module.php` in same directory as page the AJAX code is being run? Hard to troubleshoot both ends at once without knowing what is happening in console with the actual request

Comment: I know the ajax request is correct. I will include an update in my question, in 10 mins plz read the update and you will definitly know where the issue is

Comment: I managed to figure it out, but thanks for your help :) best answer

Answer (score 0):

String generated by `while` loop should be within the  `<select>...</select>` tags

```
$moduleHTML .= '<select name="modules" id="modulesDrop">'.PHP_EOL; 
$moduleHTML .= '<option value="">Please Select</option>'.PHP_EOL;  

 while($sqlstmt->fetch()) { 
     $moduleHTML .= sprintf('<option value="%1$s">%2$s - %3$s</option>'.PHP_EOL, $dbModuleId, $dbModuleNo, $dbModuleName);
} 

$moduleHTML .= '</select>'; 

echo $moduleHTML;
```

Comment: Ok but how can I include it in my code because I want it to display the drop down menu straight away on the page showing the "Please Select" option and then when the user selects a course, then I want it to include the other options in the drop down menu